# Port .Net Windows to Linux

Tags: c#, mono, ftdi

Net application that controls an FTDI device.
I use the "FTD2XX_NET.dll" c# wrapper provided by FTDI.

Now I want to port my application to ARM Linux (Raspberry Pi).
Ftdi provides a shared libary for arm linux but the c# wrapper tries to load the windows "ftd2xx.dll" instead of the linux "libftd2xx.so" library.
I use mono as c# runtime.

Are there any chances that I can get my application running? Is there a way to load the linux libary without having the wrapper source?

Comment: Have you tried creating a link that maps ftd2xx.dll to libftd2xx.so?

Answer (score 2):

If wrapper is using PInvokes and native libraries have same functions signatures. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/ should work for you.